# What is the build-tools alternative to 'make' that has a progress bar?

Tags: debian, compiling

AFAIK `make` was the beginning or grandfather of build-tools. It needs/needed `.configure` correctly done in order to spew out a binary tool/package etc. I just commented on node.

I do remember using one tool which had a build progress bar on the CLI and performed perfectly but don't remember the name. Can somebody please help me to remember?

I am looking for a modern build-tool which has minimal set of dependencies ( in Debian) and has the above features as well.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “It needs/needed `.configure` correctly done in order to spew out a binary tool/package etc. I just commented on node.”? `make` doesn’t *need* `configure`, and I don’t understand what `node` has to do with any of this. What features are you looking for, beyond a progress bar? Are you thinking of `cmake` perhaps, which produces builds with a percentage progress indicator?

Comment: I was thinking of cmake, just not remembering the name, could you make it into an answer so I can award you and the question gets answered, thank you.

Comment: sorry, just not been well to come here .

Comment: No need to apologise, take care of yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of build tools offer progress information. [CMake](https://cmake.org/) in particular produces makefiles which, by default, print out their progress:

```
Scanning dependencies of target mikmod-static
[  1%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_AF.c.o
[  1%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_aiff.c.o
[  2%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_ahi.c.o
[  3%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_aix.c.o
[  3%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_alsa.c.o
[  4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_dart.c.o
[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_ds.c.o
[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_esd.c.o
[  6%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_gp32.c.o
[  7%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_hp.c.o
[  7%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mikmod-static.dir/drivers/drv_mac.c.o
```

[The Meson Build system](http://mesonbuild.com/), or rather the build tool [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) commonly used with it, also prints progress information, in a much more compact form (it shows a single line during the build, unless something goes wrong).